# EasyMock 3 with a class:

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I am trying to mock a class like so (thank's google for code design that's difficult to use in a test environment):

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant googleAuthorizationCodeGrant = EasyMock.createMock(GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant.class);
```

Then I am setting up a mock method call like this:

```
AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = new AccessTokenResponse();
EasyMock.expect(googleAuthorizationCodeGrant.execute()).andReturn(accessTokenResponse);
```

Yet it spews an exception, because during googleAuthorizationCodeGrant.execute() it tries to run the actual code in GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant.execute().  Am I missing something here?  I would expect the cglib proxy to wrap this class and override it's methods to do nothing, as I don't want their implementation when mocking.  There should be no need for any of the business logic to remain, as I am defining the behaviour of the various method calls.

**Edit**

Note - I think there is some confusion here.  The exception is thrown on:

```
EasyMock.expect(googleAuthorizationCodeGrant.execute()).andReturn(accessTokenResponse)
```

Not when I put the mock in replay mode, as I never actually reach that code.  The reason the exception is thrown is because a member of GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant is null, and a method is invoked on it on .execute().  The member would not be null had I instantiated GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant with the new operator.  However I do not understand why EasyMock would work like this on a class because I would expect it to create a proxy which wraps the implementation to do nothing.

Here is a stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.executeUnparsed(AccessTokenRequest.java:451)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.execute(AccessTokenRequest.java:475)
at uk.co.domain.service.google.GmailContactPollerTest.testDoPoll(GmailContactPollerTest.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: can you add the stack trace from the exception to the question?

Comment: Have you set Mock object to replay state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you replayed back that mocked instance. If you have already done that and still getting the exception please put the stack trace.

Comment: In AccessTokenRequest line 451 are you calling the googleAuthorizationCodeGrant.execute() method, if so have you injected the mocked GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant into AccessTokenRequest class. If not it will call the original GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant code. Even though EasyMock would have created the proxy for this class you need to pass this mock to the calling class so that the original GoogleAuthCodeGrant is not executed.